# Cisco 3750 - EIGRP not on common subnet problen

Tags: networking, cisco, routing, eigrp

I'm getting lots of messages on a router

IGRP-IPv4:(50)(Default-IP-Routing-Table:50): Neighbor 10.13.1.251 not on common subnet for Vlan11

10.13.1.251 doesnt respond and show ip route says 10.13.1.251 is directly connected on Vlan1. This must be off one of the trunk ports but how can i find out which port this neighbor connects on so i can fix the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the subnet mask for the two Vlan interfaces doesn't match.
What does `sh run int vlan 11` say? Does it match the mask on that VLAN on other devices?

Comment: yes they don't match - vlan 11 is 10.20.1.0 255.255.255.0. Vlan 1 is 10.13.1.0 255.255.255.0. So something is misconfigured with wrong ip address, but i can't see what it is or where it connects to be able to fix

Comment: interface Vlan1
 ip address 10.13.1.254 255.255.255.0
end

interface Vlan11
 ip address 10.20.1.254 255.255.255.0
end

Comment: What are you trying to do? To establish EIGRP you need both devices on the same VLAN and the same subnet configured on the two devices.

Comment: I'm trying to see what device is wrongly configured so i can stop the error messages. I'm not sure if this error is causing any real problem, but i'd like to get rid of it. I guess some device is configured wrongly, but how can i track it. If i can get the MAC address somehow for the device i can track to an interface and then console on

Comment: Looks like you are mixing vlan 1 and 11? EIGRP will send a multicast request to discover neighbours.
Again, you need the same VLAN and same subnet to establish EIGRP (if you actually need/want EIGRP on this vlan 1, if not just set it as a passive-interface in the EIGRP config.

Comment: Thanks for that i could passive-interface for vlan1 which would get rid of the message. But  id like to find out what is 10.13.1.251 and where it connects so i can reconfigure it. Still can't see how i can track it though

Comment: Check the ARP table, should have an entry for 10.13.1.251. Then use (if you have Cisco switches...) "show mac-address-table address <MAC address>" to track it from switch to switch.